# OpenConnect VPN cuts off outside name resolution

Tags: vpn, display-resolution, openconnect

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3, the same problem occurred with 16.04.2.
I'm at a hotel and my internet connection is working.
When I VPN into work using OpenConnect, I can access website inside the corporate intranet but not the outside internet.

Here are some details -- the dnsmasq daemon is running

```
--> ps aux | grep dnsmasq
nobody    1022  0.0  0.0  52868  4132 ?        S    10:46   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-file=/var/run/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.pid --listen-address=127.0.1.1 --cache-size=0 --conf-file=/dev/null --proxy-dnssec --enable-dbus=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.dnsmasq --conf-dir=/etc/NetworkManager/dnsmasq.d
```

Prior to opening the VPN, here are the parameters:

```
--> nmcli dev show | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             4.2.2.1

-->  nslookup 4.2.2.1
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
1.2.2.4.in-addr.arpa    name = a.resolvers.level3.net.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
2.4.in-addr.arpa    nameserver = dnsauth3.level3.net.
2.4.in-addr.arpa    nameserver = dnsauth1.level3.net.
2.4.in-addr.arpa    nameserver = dnsauth2.level3.net.
```

After I open the VPN, the DNS is still reported but the resolution doesn't work:

```
--> nmcli dev show | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             4.2.2.1

-->  nslookup 4.2.2.1
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

I don't have this problem when I VPN in from home, where AT&T is my network services provider.

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that uses settings within the Network Manager interface, as opposed to tinkering with system configuration files. Or if this is not possible, I'd like to pursue this a an Ubuntu or OpenConnect bug and get it fixed in a future release. This related query, for example  


[network-only-using-one-dns-when-connected-to-vpn](https://askubuntu.com/questions/449642/network-only-using-one-dns-when-connected-to-vpn?newreg=2db77b27744541a68188481ce69bebc0)    


describes editing the `/etc/resolv.conf` file, but as far as I can tell this file is only used indirectly.

Comment: One other thing to note is that when I'm *at* work, the outside internet is visible. It looks like the VPN is only getting a subset of the DNS server assignments when this happens. Is there a way to get `dnsmasq` to list all the servers it's using? Clearly the `nmcli dev show | grep DNS` is not giving me the correct answer since it's still showing the "outside" server rather than the "inside" one.

Comment: Just as a check, the external nameserver also works while I'm VPN'd, as long as I make it explicit:  `

>nslookup 4.2.2.1 4.2.2.1
>Server:  4.2.2.1
>Address: 4.2.2.1#53
>
>Non-authoritative answer:
>1.2.2.4.in-addr.arpa name = a.resolvers.level3.net.
`

Comment: NONE OF THE MARKUP STUFF IS WORKING ABOVE: backquote, >, double-space.  HOW DO I FIX THIS???

Comment: So far the workaround is to use the network-manager pane to assign *one* DNS server to the VPN connection, and make *all* the search-domains explicit: mycompany.com, com, org, gov, edu, net. 
  
  
It looks like adding a second DNS server to the VPN doesn't help. Is this a characteristic of `dnsmasq`, that it only works with a single DNS?